# Angular Get checkbox checked value instead of boolean value

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

Currently I am working on servicenow, here we are using anularjs. I am unable to get checkbox checkvalue

Here is my code,

```js
$scope.userFavourite = function(favourite){
        alert(favourite);
    }
```

```html
<labe for="tea"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="Food" value="food" ng-true-value="food" ng-click="userFavourite(value)"/>Food</labe>
  <labe for="tea"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="Books" value="tea" ng-true-value="tea" ng-click="userFavourite()"/>Books</labe>
  <labe for="tea"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="Travel" value="travel" ng-true-value="travel" ng-click="userFavourite(Travel)"/>Travel</labe>
```

Thanks your value time spending on this

Answer (score -1):

There is multiple ways you can able to resolve this issue like:

> use `ng-change` to call a function when the checkbox value changes:

```html
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="food" ng-change="checkboxChanged()" />
```

```js
$scope.checkboxChanged = function(){
 console.log($scope.food)
}
```

> Using `ng-click` - Pass the model value to your function

```html
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="food" ng-click="checkboxClicked(food)" />
```

```js
$scope.checkboxClicked = function(value){
 console.log(value)
}
```

> As you can also remove the `value` attribute and just use `ng-model` values:

```html
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="food" ng-click="userFavourite(food)" />
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="books" ng-click="userFavourite(books)" />
```

```js
$scope.userFavourite = function(value){
 console.log(value)
}
```